# On the groups of order $4p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $4p^2$ such that $G \cong (\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2) \ltimes G^{\prime}$, $Z(G) \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$ and $p$ is an odd prime number. Then I want to know $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the normal subgroup of order $p^2$.

If $P$ is cyclic then its subgroup of order $p$ is normal.

Otherwise $P$ is elementary abelian, and a Sylow-$2$-subgroup, $\langle s,t\rangle$ say acts on it. By hypothesis one of these, $t$ say, centralises everything. The action of $s$ on $P$ can be thought of as that of a linear transformation $S$ of order $2$ on the $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$; as the minimal polynomial of $S$ divides $X^2-1$ we have that   $S$ is diagonalisable, and then any eigenvector generates the required subgroup.

Comment: Thanks Dear 
ancientmathematician. But i need a proof without Linear Algebra!

Comment: Oh dear, that is a very perverse requirement. The whole point of mastering linear algebra is to save us constantly having to re-invent the wheel. No doubt some clever person will oblige in due course.

Comment: Dear ancientmathematician, thanks any way